# Using DateTimeFormatter over SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I'm refactoring some code and I'm trying to distinguish what problem is being solved. The function of `formatDateRfc1123` is obvious, but what's the added value of the added code?

In the first commit this was the function, which could crash for reasons unknown to me:

```
public static String formatDateRfc1123(final Date timestamp) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatRf1123 = new SimpleDateFormat(RFC_1123);
    formatRf1123.setTimeZone(GMT_ZONE);
    return formatRfc1123.format(timestamp);
}
```

Later, that got refactored to solve the crash:

```
public static String formatDateRfc1123(final Date timestamp, final int buildVersion) {
    if (buildVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODE_O) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(RFC_1123, US);
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timestamp.getTime());
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(GMT_ZONE.getID());
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);
        return dateTimeFormatter.format(zonedDateTime);
    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat formatRf1123 = new SimpleDateFormat(RFC_1123);
        formatRf1123.setTimeZone(GMT_ZONE);
        return formatRfc1123.format(timestamp);
    }
}
```

There's an old user story linked to the added code, but that only links to a removed Fabric crash log. So, I only know it can crash, not what exception was thrown for what value.

For what value and SDK version is it likely to crash?

Comment: `java.time` is unfortunately only part of the code snippet that did not crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first three lines of your code using `java.time` has been overly complicated making the calculation error-prone. I recommend you use the out-of-the-box constants to avoid any kind of ambiguity and error. Given below is the recommended way to do it:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(formatDateRfc1123(new Date()));
    }

    public static String formatDateRfc1123(final Date timestamp) {
        // Use the out-of-the-box formatter
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.withLocale(Locale.US);

        // Use Date#toInstant to convert it into Instant
        Instant instant = timestamp.toInstant();

        // Use the out-of-the-box constant for UTC (or GMT)
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneOffset.UTC;

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);
        // ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(zoneId); //This is simpler

        return dateTimeFormatter.format(zonedDateTime);
    }
}
```

Note that the three-letter string representing a time zone is error-prone. You should always use the full name of the time zone i.e. `Continent/City`. Given below is an example to demonstrate it.

```
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("EDT");
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: EDT
    at java.base/java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getProvider(ZoneRulesProvider.java:279)
    at java.base/java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(ZoneRulesProvider.java:234)
    at java.base/java.time.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:120)
    at java.base/java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:408)
    at java.base/java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:356)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

The `SimpleDateFormat` won't even throw an exception and silently format the date-time at UTC (or GMT). Such dangerous it is!

### Incorrect:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-05T01:36:48Z
```

### Correct:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-04T20:36:05-05:00
```

Note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).